# How can I make image linking to attachment page (rather than a direct link)?

Tags: images

I currently have the [Modern Style Theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/modern-style) installed.

If you click on an image on my page, it links directly to the highest resolution version of that image. ([Example post with one image](http://martin-thoma.com/what-is-the-best-programming-language/))

I would rather like it to link to an "attachment page", where the description of the image is also showen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert a new media, you get to choose the **Link URL**. Under the field, there are 3 buttons, simply click **Attachment Post URL** to link to it.